# Is v8cgi via FastCGI possible in IIS7 and how?

Tags: javascript, iis-7, fastcgi, v8, serverside-javascript

Is it possible to run server-side JS in **IIS7** using **v8cgi** via **FastCGI**? I already have FastCGI setup in IIS7 and know how to setup up PHP via FastCGI for IIS7 like this (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/).

Comment: Did you figure this out?  If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Unfortunately I gave up and did it in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a quick download of v8cgi. Basically, you can follow these steps:

- Deploy v8cgi somewhere on your machine
- Add a handler mapping (like for PHP), for example for **.js* files
- Use the FastCgiModule for that mapping
- The executable will be "C:[Path to your v8cgi installation]\v8cgi.exe"
- The name can be anything you like

These steps should register v8cgi.exe to be executed by IIS and FastCGI.

Comment: Hey I tried that but get a server error. C:\v8cgi\v8cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Comment: Anything in the WIndows event log?